# Android fragment getChildAt() crashing sometimes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I have a fragment that is getting inflated and displayed correctly. I want to update some views, but instead of doing it inside `onCreateView()`, I'm doing it inside a method of the fragment, called `showContent()`, because this function will be called many times.

This works, but for some reason sometimes it crashes, especially the first time I launch the app. The error I get is:
`` `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference` ``

Here is the method of the fragment (changed for simplicity):

```
    public void showContent(ActionInfo currAction) { 
        //ActionInfo is a custom class 
        //'amount' is public int variable 
        //'who' is public String variable

        switch ( currAction.amount ) {
            case 1: 
                ((TextView)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.Seat1)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setText(currAction.who); 
                break;
            case 2: 
                ((TextView)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.Seat2)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setText(currAction.who); 
                break;
            //case...
        }
        //...
    }
```

The xml for the Seats are like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Seat1"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <include layout="@layout/player_names"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

layout/player_names is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/player_names_card_view"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#795548"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It looks like I try to update them when `onCreateView()` hasn't happened yet, but I've even tried setting up flags to change that and it didn't work.

**EDIT:** To be clear, I want to be calling `showContent()` many times, from the parent activity, so no calling from `onViewCreated()` etc

**EDIT 2:** After what I've seen and I tried, I understood that the problem is pretty much finding out at which point in the parent activity both the parent activity and the fragment are fully created, so i can safely call `fragment.showContent()` **from the parent activity**

Comment: why you don't directly access player_names_text_view ?
getView().findViewById(R.id.player_names_text_view)

Comment: Call your `showContent` method in `onViewCreated` to avoid **NPE** because it is not fully inflated in `onCreateView`

Comment: yes as david said just make sure showContent should be called after view properly inflated otherwise you will get null.

Comment: the layout inside the include is not unique, it is used many times, therefore the id 'player_names_text_view' is useless since there are a lot of instances of it. I'm going to delete it, sorry for the confusion. 
Calling `showContent()` inside `onViewCreated()` is not an option, since I want to be calling it from the parent activity.

Comment: @David Also I don't want to call showContent in onViewCreated, I want to call showContent from the parent activity

Comment: Okay but you have to make sure your layout is initialized, so what about setting an` init boolean` in `onViewCreated` and show your content only if **initialized is set to true** ... Also if you have an **NPE** some parts of your lifecycle management are not implmented correct. If you are not sure about it provide code from where you are creating the fragment and the part where you want to call `showContent`

Comment: @David I think I solved it, by declaring the seats in the `onViewCreated()` and accessing them in the from there. I don't know though why it is working now, there doesn't seem to be any real difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the `RelativeLayout` `Seat1` , after `onCreateView()` with declaring and linking the `relativelayout` on `OnActivityCreated()` and use it in `showContent()` function.

Comment: help me understand your answer. I understand the part about accessing it after `onCreateView()` because that would mean that it was created for sure. But I want to use `fragment.showContent()` from the parent activity, so how would I know that the fragment has been correctly inflated by that time?

Comment: in order to do that ,if your parent uses the FragmentTransaction to replace the fragment ,you could add the fragment with tag > let say that tag will be the (YourFragment.class.getSimpleName() ) so you have the ref. tag to your fragment , on the fragment itself you may use an additional boolean flag "isInflated" to indicate that fragment has been inflated before , you may also set that flag to "true" on onViewCreated() method or on onActivtyCreated() ,when nee to update get fragment by it's tag through SupportFragmentManager and then check flag then call the function.

Comment: That might work but I can't loop forever until the flag changes on the parent activity for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line of code with this where TextViewID is the id of the textview in player xml layout.

```
 ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.TextViewID)).setText(currAction.who);
```

"include" just copy the layout for reuse purpose you can use "include" layout elements as single layout.

Comment: That was not the problem. I found the problem is that, sometimes, the activity that creates the fragment has not finished getting created, so getView() returns null. In the same way, I realised that getActivity() also sometimes returns null.

Comment: In that case make a variable mView global and inflate your view in it and for getActivity() pass your  context of Activity here because sometimes when view is not loaded completely it gets null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

boolean isViewCreated = false;
ActionInfo currAction;
.
.
.

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    isViewCreated = true;
    .
    .
    if(currAction != null){
        showContent(currAction);
    }
}

public void showContent(ActionInfo currAction) { 

    if(isViewCreated){
    //ActionInfo is a custom class 
    //'amount' is public int variable 
    //'who' is public String variable

    switch ( currAction.amount ) {
        case 1: 
            ((TextView)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.Seat1)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setText(currAction.who); 
            break;
        case 2: 
            ((TextView)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)getView().findViewById(R.id.Seat2)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setText(currAction.who); 
            break;
        //case...
    }
    //...
    } else {
        this.currAction = currAction;
    }
}
}
```

I have added a `boolean` value to check to see if `onCreateView` is called or not, so that `getView` won't return `null` value.

Comment: for the other case you can maintain the state of `currAction` inside the fragment so that when `onCreateView` is called you can call this function to update the view from onCreateView passing saved value of `currAction`.

Comment: op here, the problem is that I don't want to call `showContent()` from `onCreateView()`, I want to call it from parent activity like `fragment.showContent()`. So pretty much I don't know at which point in the Activity both the activity and the fragment are loaded so I can safely call `fragment.showContent()` and not get null at `getView()` or `getApplicationContext()` etc

Comment: see you call it from `activity` but in case your `onCreateView()` is not called then it will update the object inside fragment and once `onCreateView` is called, it will call the `showContent` function. To provide the complete solution as asked by you, i have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you explore `FragmentActivity::onResumeFragments()`?

Comment: As I have stated, I want to call the method from the parent activity, so this doesn't help.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. Override `onResumeFragments` in the activity and call your `fragment.showContent` from there.

Comment: You are right then. Although in my specific case I can't use it because it will always call the showContent with fixed values, which I don't want.
I generally solved my problem, by saving the activity in my fragment with this
`@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }`
although it is deprecated, but the non depricated didn't work for me